# Enter date with jQuery datepicker & with keyboard in a user friendly way

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a field with the jQuery UI datepicker working properly. It allows the user to select a date with the UI tool or type a date with the keyboard. I'm using dateFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy".

[image]

Now the users want to enter the date with the keyboard more easily. The users dont want to type "13-04-2023", but only the numbers "13042023", and then it should show up on screen as "13-04-2023", just like an inputfield with a type="Date".

Does someone have a working solution for this?

Or should I switch to the inputfield with type="Date"?

Comment: I switched to the native date input https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date